# Mithril VM DOM diffing does not detect diff in attached event handler

Tags: reactjs, mithril.js, virtual-dom

This may not be a Mithril specific question but VM DOM diffing in general. While "redrawing" a page and you attach a new event handler, remove an event handler, or change the event handler associated with an event such as "onclick", it seems that the VM DOM diffing will not detect the change and I have to explicitly force a rerendering of the "real" DOM.

Is there a good pattern to handle these situations.

Answer (score 1):

In Mithril specifically, `onclick` and all the `on`-handlers automatically trigger a redraw after the handler function has completed. However, if your onclick handler does real DOM manipulation (3rd party libraries such as jQuery or an animation suite) you need to use the `config` attribute:
http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html#the-config-attribute
which gets called after the page has been rendered.

With regards to *changing* event handlers, it depends on when in the render cycle you make the change. I'd have to see some code. If it's not too inconvenient, calling redraw manually is not a bad thing. If the redraw strategy is "diff" you won't pay a penalty.

And lastly, if you are introducing your own events, consider using m.startComputation/m.endComputation in your event handlers. These provide much finer grain control and a redraw is automatically called. 
http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.computation.html